# How to Delete rows in Google Sheet after 8 days with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

need help, I am a beginner coder, I want to delete data in A column
today is 2023-07-05
if a1=2023-06-01 delete this row, a2=2023-06-02 delete this row, a3=2023-07-05 not delete row
you can see my code at my image link, sorry for my English and my skill.

thank a lot for your help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN5TA.png)

```js
function deleteRow1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  //Logger.log(data);
  var pdate = new Date();
  //Logger.log(pdate);
  var nDays = 8;
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24 * nDays;
  var cutOfDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldDate), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  //Logger.log(cutOfDate);
  for (let i = data.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    Logger.log(data[i]);
    if (pdate - cutOfDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: ok, now I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script. It will check column A for the date and once the date is older than 8 days it will be deleted. Add a trigger event to it to perform this script on a daily basis in the morning to automate it.

```
function deleteOldRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Fix time difference issues

  var deletedData = []; // Record deleted data

  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) { // Last row excl header.
    var rowDate = new Date(data[i][0]); // In this case 0 stands for the first column. If the date is located in column B you have to switch 0 to 1

    if (rowDate < today - 8 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) { // Check date with todays date
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1); // Delete the row (by chaning the number you can add the number of headers (in this case 1))
    }
  }
}
```